# Comparing two arraylist in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I have the arraylist which has some process names like "Notepad", "mspaint"

I want to check the values of above arraylist against the following :

Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();

If the process "Notepad" is not there in Procs, then i want to use that value
for further requirement.

How do i find the value of my arraylist which is missing in Procs ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are smarter answers, but i will post a naive one because its easier to understand

```
List<string> myprocs; // populated with process names
Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process proc in Procs)
{
  if(myprocs.Contains(proc.ProcessName))
  {
     myprocs.Remove(proc.ProcessName);
  }
}
// whatever that is left over in myprocs at this point is your remainder process names.
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Go through the list one-by-one using [ArrayList.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains%28VS.80%29.aspx)

2) If LINQ is available use the set difference: [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386962.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the `Except` method provided by LINQ. But if you are using Arraylist instead of List<>, I guess you are using .NET 1.